# Point Coordinates to x and y cordinates in variables doesnt really work

Tags: java, coordinates, jbutton, point

i just try to program pong with the use of java swing components.

My problem ist, that i need to store the coordinates of my JButton (my Paddle) in variables to be able to manipulate the position of the Button when moving.

I tried doing it that way:

```
int posP1_x= paddel1.getLocation().getX(); //Error
```

When compiling it says, that there is a lossy conversion from double to int. (But the retrun value of getX should be int and in the Point-Class the values are also stored as ints). When i try declaring posP1_x as double and print the variables value on the console, it always prints 0.0. But when i print paddel1.getLocation().getX() directly, it works...

```
double posP1_x= paddel1.getLocation().getX(); //Works

System.out.println(paddel1.getLocation().getX());    //Prints double value eg 110.0

System.out.println(posP1_x);    //Prints double value  with 0. --> 0.0
```

What could be the solution to save JButton Coordinates in Variables.

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getX()`. Use `.x`. That's it. For example:

```
// either
int posP1_x= (int) paddel1.getLocation().getX();

// or
int posP1_x= paddel1.getLocation().x;
```

More importantly, look at the relevant API **before** posting here. If you'd simply look at the [Point API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), you'd have your answer.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesnt really work. Still cant use the variable (prints 0). When i use paddel1.getLocation().x in Syso, it prints out correctly.  Sorry I am a beginner and dont understand why that doesnt work

Comment: @Rob: then you've got bugs elsewhere in your code, in code we're not seeing and we can't help you with this. This *does* answer your original question (questions are only supposed to ask *one* question). For the other problem you will want to do some debugging.

Comment: @Rob: please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: @Rob unrelated bit but why would you use a JButton as a paddle? I would use a Rectangle since a pong paddle doesn't need or use a JButton's functionality.

Comment: OK thank. You, i am going to check that out.  Its just funnyy, that when i set posP1_x=1;   printing out the Variables value works perfectly. But only when assigning the coordinates to that variable it just wont work...